# Spin spherical functions in hydrogen-like solution to Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation, spherical-harmonics

I saw a video where the following equality is wrote for the angular part of the solution of the Dirac equation for hydrogen-like atoms:
\begin{align}
\Omega^{j=l\pm 1/2}_{lm}&=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2l+1}}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle \pm \sqrt{l\pm m+\frac{1}{2}}\,Y_{l,m-1/2}(\theta,\varphi)\\
\displaystyle \sqrt{l\mp m+\frac{1}{2}}\,Y_{l,m+1/2}(\theta,\varphi)
\end{array}
\right)\\&=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pm 2k+1}}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle \sqrt{\pm k- m+\frac{1}{2}}\,Y_{\pm k,m-1/2}(\theta,\varphi)\\
\displaystyle -\text{sgn}(k)\sqrt{\mp k +m+\frac{1}{2}}\,Y_{\pm k,m+1/2}(\theta,\varphi)
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
Where $k=-l-1$ for $j=l+1/2$ and $l$ for $j=l-1/2$, and $Y_{l,m}$ are the spherical harmonics. I don't know how to prove this equality, especialy the $``\text{sgn}(k)``$ term. I can't figure out why the $\pm m$ and $\mp m $ are changed into $-m$ and $+m$ and why the $\pm$ sign disapears in the first line. Anyone knows how to prove this?

Comment: Is the order of the two lines swapped? That is, the strictly positive expression is second in the $\ell$ formulation, but first in the $k$ formulation.

Comment: @rob no because the spherical harmonics are not swapped.

Comment: Using that "k" is an unnecesary complication.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the formula is correct. The expression under the square root $\sqrt{\pm 2 k+1}$ seems negative.

Comment: It seems like you would choose the negative sign only to make the expression well-behaved for negative $k$.

Comment: @rob : I would think one has to choose the same sign as in the "left-most" hand side (containing $\Omega$). Anyway, I am skeptical about a formula copied from a video:-)

Answer (score 0):

The spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell m}$ are nonzero for $0 \leq |m| \leq \ell$ and are polynomials in $\cos\theta$ of order $\ell$.  (Note that, [when tabulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics), they are frequently simplified using the identity $\cos^2\theta - 1 = \sin^2\theta$.)

The notation $Y_{\pm k, m+1/2}$ suggests that we must choose the sign so that $k$ is positive. However, you've said the options are $k=\ell$ or $k=-\ell-1$.  There is no recurrence relation where $Y_{\ell,m}$ is a polynomial with the same order as $Y_{|-\ell-1|,m}$, so the two sets of expressions are different if $k<0$.